# How I can stroke individual line in same Path - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, path

I have a path named - path . So now I want to add dynamic lines where particular line will have individual stroke on it. SO that every single line can acheive their own width from my point model.

Here my code :

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
    var startingPoint : CGPoint = .zero
    var currentGroupID : Int = 0
    
    if( points.count > 0 ){
         startingPoint = points[0].point
    } else {
        return Path()
    }
    
    var path = Path()
    
    
    
    for point in points{
        
        
        if(currentGroupID != point.groupID){
            currentGroupID = point.groupID
            path.move(to: point.point)
        }
        path.addLine(to: point.point)
        
        startingPoint = point.point
        
        print("Starting Point - \(startingPoint)")
        print("Current - \(point.point)")
        
        
        
    }
    return path
        
        
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you want to achieve? What should the endresult look like? A quick drawing would suffice.

Comment: You can't achieve that with a single path.  Why not create a structure that associates a path, and line width, and other attributes you want to associate with a path, and then loop over an array of these paths drawing them with the appropriate attributes.